# crystal report suppress main footer on page where subreport appear

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report:

> - header report
> - header page (a,b,c,d,e)
> - header group 1
> - header group 2
> - details (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
> - footer group 1
> - footer group 2
> - footer report (subreport)
> - footer

what I want to do is to make disappear the last footer on the page where sub report appear.

I am new of crystal report, never used, in new company was giving me this work to do was searching on google but i need instruction of beginner :-)

the version of crystal report is 2008

thanks to who can help me.

Comment: What is last footer on the page? Are you discussing about page footer or group footer

Comment: is the last on the list, how to check if is page footer or group footer? thanks

Comment: In any report for a page page footer will be last footer...rest all comes before that

Comment: what i want to remove is the footer that is repeating in each page of the report but remove it only when in that page there is the subreport.

Comment: which footer are you mentioning about? be specific else how can we know what are you trying to do

Comment: i would like to be specific but i don't know how to tell you wich is, where i must to look in the software? i think is the main report footer why is repeating in each page. i have find out a suppress command on this footer and i was inserting this formula PageNumber=TotalPageCount it function but only if the subreport is one page, i have some case where the subreport generate 3 page or more.

Comment: ok I got it you are mentioning about `page footer` as it is the compulsory footer that will be present for every page.. now what are you trying to display in page footer? and does page footer and sub report footer has the same information?